# Does pushing a git tag also push the commit?

Tags: git, github

Here's what I did...

```
git checkout -b test-branch
### add a line of text to a .md file, then...
git commit -am 'a commit that will never be pushed'
git tag my-tag
git push --tags
### NOTE: I ONLY pushed the tag (not the branch)
```

So...

I have *not* pushed the commit

I have *not* pushed the branch the commit is on

But...

When I view the [tag in github](https://github.com/sfletche/til/releases/tag/my-tag)

Then click on the associated SHA
[image]
I see [the actual (un-pushed) commit](https://github.com/sfletche/til/commit/66f7af85c4788f294c5c53b530883c304e51ad99)

[image]

I thought a Tag was only a pointer to a SHA.

How is it I am seeing the contents of an un-pushed commit?  And what is going on?

Comment: A tag is a ref.  A branch is a ref.  It doesn't make any sense to push a ref without also pushing the commit that is referenced, so `git push --tags` pushes all the commits necessary to ensure that the refs on the remote have something to reference.  The first line of the `git-push` man page reads: "Updates remote refs using local refs, while sending objects necessary to complete the given refs."

Comment: It's interesting that the man page says "Updates" instead of "Update", as this usage seems similar to the usage in a commit message.

Comment: It's really, really useful to understand (at least at a high level) how Git is just a directed acyclic graph of commits, with pointers into that graph. Establishing that correct mental model is key to understanding otherwise surprising behavior. I don't have a good tutorial or reference to link, but Googling "git dag" yielded https://devtutorial.io/git-is-a-directed-acyclic-graph-dag-p1182.html which looks good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have not pushed the commit

Yes you have, whether you know it or not, otherwise the remote would reject the tag.

You never "push the commits" manually, you push them implicitly while pushing a branch or tag that references the commits.  Tags and branches are more or less identical. Commits are not "on branches", anymore than they are "on tags". Branches and tags are pointers to commits, and when you push one of either type, the commits it references must also be pushed.

The same way you don't have to ask Git to specifically download all the commits when you check out a branch. Git does this for you.

> I thought a Tag was only a pointer to a SHA (not a container for commits...)

Yes, **exactly** the same as a branch. They're both just pointers to commit IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Git traffics in commits. A commit is a thing. Everything else is just information about those commits.

A tag *refers* to a commit. Saying checkout a tag checks out a commit. Saying push a tag pushes a commit.

You cannot push a tag *without* pushing the commit that it points to (along with everything reachable from it that the remote may lack). A tag pointing to a nonexistent commit would be a broken repo!

(Of course, typically when we push tags, the remote already has the commits referred to, so no actual transfer of commits takes place. But in formulating this edge case, you arranged things so that the remote did *not* already have this commit.)

It's the same as a branch. A branch refers to a commit. Checking out a branch checks out a commit. Pushing a branch pushes a commit. Pushing a branch doesn't transfer just a name, it transfers commits.

Comment: It's like "eat a banana". You are not eating the _word_ banana. You are eating the thing that word refers to.

Comment: Let's assume hypothetically that I have a valid reason to do this, and on purpose. Does normal git gc take care of the unreferenced commits for us?